# Meaning of scale ratio in QGIS

Tags: qgis, scale, units

I am new to using QGIS and I cannot find definitive information about how to intellectually use the scale ratio shown at the bottom toolbar. There is a number of predefined scales, with the format being "1:xxx". The manual talk about changing the scale units from millimeters to miles; as well as setting your own increments and such, but it doesn't straight up tell you how to read this scale. For example, ArcGIS's documentation explicitly says:

> When a map is displayed at a scale of 1:100 (or simply 100.0), 1cm on the display represents 1m (100cm) in the real world. A scale of 100,000.0 means that 1cm on the map display represents 1km (100,000cm) in the real world, and so on.

I cannot find any information such as this for QGIS. So can someone tell me what units the scale ratio in QGIS is measured in?

Comment: I honestly can't think of anything else that a map scale could actually mean - What ESRI have put is literally the classroom definition of a map scale. There isn't any possible other definition in any GIS application that I can think of. Its a text book definition across all platforms as far as I know.

Comment: @nr_aus Well the thing is, I read a QGIS document from an Indian professor stating that: "USGS topographic maps are printed at 1:100,000 scale (1 inch on the map equals 100,000 inches in the real world or about 1.58 miles). In QGIS you can scale your map to any scale, but you are also offered standard scales to choose from."

So is the standard to use 1cm or 1inch? For someone not in the this field; its hard to assume these things. However, if what you say is true, thats great.

Comment: In a 1:100k scale map I'd say it was 1cm = 1km, but the important part is realizing it's a scalar (unitless).

Comment: I know that in the European world, the International System of Units, i.e the modern metric system is primarily used. However in most of the west, the imperial system is primarily used. The fact that you can change the scale in QGIS, to whatever unit you want, makes it difficult for a new user to come in and know how to realistically use the software if their isnt a static unit mentioned for the value of the "1" in the ratio.

Comment: ok ive recommended a slight wording change to your question, to highlight the 'units' as being part of the understanding. Vince's answer above is probably the most succinct with regards to units.

Comment: On a 1:100 map, 1 inch on on the map represents 100 inches in the real world. In the same time, 1 cm on the map measures 100 cm (1m) in the real world. Scales have nothing to do with a specific unit. It is a ratio of 1 to 100 for **any** unit. Inventing you own length measurement unit, the map would still be 1:100